# Confusing instructions of exam review, java

Tags: java, if-statement, methods, static

So I am studying for my exam tomorrow and part of it is completing a static method. I have completed all, but one part which is confusing me. Thought I might ask for help.

Instructions are below, I bolded the confusing parts, and ill explain why below.

A. Complete the implementation this static method without the use of any standard Java Math library method. *Use an ’if’ statement only when throwing an exception.*

```
/** 
* Computes the series n + n^3 + n^5 + ... n^k. 
* k-1 is used if k is even.
* @param n the base of the series 
* @param k the bound on the exponent of the last term of the series
* @throw IllegalArgumentException when k is less than 1
*/ 
public double oddSeries(double n, int k) {
    if (k < 1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("K is less than 1");
    }
    double tempN = n;
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        tempN = tempN + (n * n);

    return tempN;
}
```

So I threw the IllegalArgumentException, and used the one if statement allowed. How do I check to see see if k is even without an if statement or switch statement? 
Because generally we would do

```
Boolean kEven = false;
if (k % 2 = 0)
kEven = true;
```

Comment: `k = ( k % 2 == 0 ) ? k -1 : k ; ` k will be assigned k-1 if k is even otherwise it will remain k

Comment: I think ternary operator will be considered as if usage.

Comment: You are not computing this correctly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have to check if k is even since you have to use k-1 in that case. Just perform this operation:

```
k = k - 1 + (k % 2);
```

When k is even it will perform k-1 operation. If k is odd it will not change k value.

Comment: This is the best answer...deleted mine.

Comment: Seems the right reasoning just the wrong math... If K is even (i.e 4) you'll get  4 - (0)  = 4.. The instructions say if K is even then use K-1

Comment: @Keammoort glad is changed

Comment: Thank you for the help, I plugged this in and tried a few numbers. It works just like stated, and I can see why it does!